# n.default.compile is not a function in production (Nuxt 2 + Vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, compilation, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

So, i have this component that use Vue.compile:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

.
.
.

const res = Vue.compile(this.template)
this.templateRender = res.render
```

This works in development environment but not in production.

In production it's returning this error:
`TypeError: n.default.compile is not a function`

I don't know exactly what is happening.
Can someone help me?

I'm using `Nuxt v2.15.8` with `Vuetify v2.6.12`.

I've tried others libs, like the `vue-template-compiler v2.6.14`, and a lot more stuff.